# When Using BioPython, Function Doesn't Iterate Over the Entire List

Tags: python, web-scraping, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm trying to search PubMed using search terms derived from a CSV file. I've combined the search terms into a form understandable by Biopython's Entrez module, like so:

```
term1 = ['"' + name + " AND " + disease + '"' for name, disease in zip(names, diseases)]
```

where 'names' and 'diseases' refers to the parameters I'm combining into a search using eSearch.
Subsequently, to execute the search, this is the code I wrote:

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "theofficialvelocifaptor@gmail.com"
for entry in range(0, len(term1)):
 handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term=term1[entry], retmax="10")
 record = Entrez.read(handle)
 record["IdList"]
 print("The first 10 are\n{}".format(record["IdList"]))
```

Now, what I'm expecting from the code is, to iterate the function over the entire list stored in `term1`. However, this is the output I'm getting:

```
['Botanical name', 'Asystasia salicifalia', 'Asystasia salicifalia', 'Asystasia salicifalia', 'Barleria strigosa', 'Justicia procumbens', 'Justicia procumbens', 'Strobilanthes auriculata', 'Thunbergia laurifolia', 'Thunbergia similis']
['Disease', 'Puerperal illness', 'Puerperium', 'Puerperal disorder', 'Tonic', 'Lumbago', 'Itching', 'Malnutrition', 'Detoxificant', 'Tonic']
The first 10 are
['31849133', '31751652', '31359527', '31178344', '31057654', '30725751', '28476677', '27798405', '27174082', '26923540']
The first 10 are
[]
The first 10 are
[]
The first 10 are
[]
The first 10 are
[]
The first 10 are
[]
The first 10 are
The first 10 are
[]
The first 10 are
[]
The first 10 are
[]
```

Surely, there's something I'm missing, because the iteration seems to be shorting out prematurely. I've been at it for a solid 5 hours at the time of writing, and I feel very silly. I should also mention that I am new to Python, so if I'm making any obvious mistakes, I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is working fine, there are no pubmed results for the last 9 term/disease combinations.

Comment: Thanks. Someone rewrote the whole code, but it was incomplete, and there's a bunch of other problems I'm facing. I'll open a new thread for that when I can. I'd request admins to kindly close this thread.